# HP Deskjet Ink Advantage 2130/2135 software installation (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: printing, hp, scanner

Although the built in drivers for the printer is working fine and with the help of the "Document Scanner" software I can manage to scan the documents but unable to find some features provided by HP proprietory software like the ink-level estimator feature...

So, Yesterday I'd downloaded the HPLIP from https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/ and followed the installation procedure and all is well until...

1. I realized that after the installation the "Ubuntu Software" was not working... Then rebooted the system but still that problem persists... Don't know whether any other software had been affected or not...
2. When I run the sudo apt clean(autoclean and autoremove)... The HP icon got vanished as well as the HP system tray icon too got vanished...

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: 1) Yeah it's always available as it is maintained by HP itself, infact the HPLIP package too ships with many Linux destros... The fact is I'm not getting the required information regarding my catrige ink-level status which are available with the official HPLIP package...

Comment: Thanks a lot... Atleast got some idea from there... As Ubuntu comes preinstall with some features of HPLIP... From there I thought i need only the hplip-gui package... And it works now... Thanks a lot once again...